# Fabricjs : Resize group automatically with members

Tags: fabricjs

Codesandbox here : https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-elgamal-c0ud5?file=/src/Rectangle.jsx

Hello,

I am trying to resize a group automatically when I one of its members grow. When I draw a rectangle on the canvas with a click and drag, a group is created containing the rectangle and a textbox. However, the whole group is not resized with the rectangle. Can someone help me solve this? Thank you.

Comment: do you want when creating a new object to add the old one into the current selection?

Comment: Each time I click and drag I want to create a rectangle and a text associated, that is why I have to group them. The group just does not want to resize with the rectangle.

Comment: do you mind if I write you in typescript how I would do just to give you an idea? basically I would create an active selection?

Comment: just added a working example and a code correction to my answer.Best

Answer (score 0):

I would try make usage of **Active Selection** on mouse up

```
    canvas.discardActiveSelection()
    const activeSelelection = new fabric.ActiveSelection([rect, text], {
      canvas: canvas
    });
    canvas.setActiveObject(activeSelection)
```

[working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-varahamihira-y192k?file=/src/Rectangle.jsx)